# JavaScript - formatting date with current timezone

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am using the moment.js library. I have dates in this format: `"2014-06-19T18:00:00+02:00"` (string). I want to display the date formatted with the user's timezone.

moment.js docs specifies to use `moment("2014-06-19T18:00:00+02:00").utc().format()`

My questions are:

- How can I set the timezone once and not have to put `.utc()` every time?
- How can I test the timezone functionality? Should I change my computer's clock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `.utc()` would actually translate the value you put in to UTC.  If you want the user's local time zone, then you should just omit that and call `.format()`.

That you passed a +02:00 offset with the original value doesn't matter.  By default, moment will adjust the value to the user's time zone.

On the other hand, if you want to *keep* the offset you provided, regardless of the user's time zone, then you can use the [`parseZone`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/) function.